# How to remove all elements from array that do not have field containing specific string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is some of the result obtained from an `ElasticSearch` query ..

```
"buckets": [{
    "key": "another_service_name:0.0.1",
    "doc_count": 105,
    "containers": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [{
            "key": "7eaf4933b0366f7212f30f9f3c315672ea18e026922d0651b29b844763be6b0a",
            "doc_count": 105,
            "someField": {
                "value": 1.2708647376015072
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    "key": "my_service_name:0.0.1",
    "doc_count": 200,
    "containers": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [{
            "key": "4c27931147386d49e90f581a1d5cb22f53cda00b16107864cad9eff32f61d776",
            "doc_count": 100,
            "someField": {
                "value": 77.9621390914917
            }
        }, {
            "key": "392e7e6981cd4c24c526ffda03977b7984ebcae58194680c82940af4acec4748",
            "doc_count": 100,
            "someField": {
                "value": 76.63604362487793
            }
        }]
    }
}]
```

Is there a simple 1-liner to remove any elements from the outter `buckets` array that do not have the `key` containing `my_service_name`?

I know I could loop over the array, use `indexOf` and `splice` .. but is there a shorter way?

I would like the result to look like this ..

```
"buckets": [{
    "key": "my_service_name:0.0.1",
    "doc_count": 200,
    "containers": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [{
            "key": "4c27931147386d49e90f581a1d5cb22f53cda00b16107864cad9eff32f61d776",
            "doc_count": 100,
            "someField": {
                "value": 77.9621390914917
            }
        }, {
            "key": "392e7e6981cd4c24c526ffda03977b7984ebcae58194680c82940af4acec4748",
            "doc_count": 100,
            "someField": {
                "value": 76.63604362487793
            }
        }]
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var queryResults = /* your result as above */;

var myServices = queryResults.filter(function(element) {
    return element.key.indexOf('my_service_name') >= 0;
})
```

In ES6 it's possible to shorten this to:

```
let queryResults = /* your result as above */;

let myServices = queryResults.filter(element => element.key.includes('my_service_name'))
```

Comment: hint: in ES6 you also have [String.prototype.includes()](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), or in this case better [String.prototype.startsWith()](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), wich are more expressive than messing around with `indexOf()`

Comment: Thanks, `includes` is probably better but `startsWith` is probably not appropriate as all we know is that the key is _"containing"_ the string.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner can be the [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, like this:

```
buckets.filter( item => /my_service_name:/i.test(item.key) );
```

As lonesomeday mentions, the arrow function is not working in Internet Explorer (and filter might not be working to), to still use this almost one liner, you could rewrite it as:

```
buckets.filter( function(item) { return /my_service_name:/i.test( item.key ); } );
```

To support filter in Internet Explorer, you can use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) supplied on the MDN page

```js
var buckets = [{
    "key": "another_service_name:0.0.1",
    "doc_count": 105,
    "containers": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [{
            "key": "7eaf4933b0366f7212f30f9f3c315672ea18e026922d0651b29b844763be6b0a",
            "doc_count": 105,
            "someField": {
                "value": 1.2708647376015072
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    "key": "my_service_name:0.0.1",
    "doc_count": 200,
    "containers": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [{
            "key": "4c27931147386d49e90f581a1d5cb22f53cda00b16107864cad9eff32f61d776",
            "doc_count": 100,
            "someField": {
                "value": 77.9621390914917
            }
        }, {
            "key": "392e7e6981cd4c24c526ffda03977b7984ebcae58194680c82940af4acec4748",
            "doc_count": 100,
            "someField": {
                "value": 76.63604362487793
            }
        }]
    }
}];

console.log( buckets.filter( item => /my_service_name:/i.test(item.key) ) );
```

Comment: Yes, though note that you will need to rewrite this if you want to support IE.

Comment: @lonesomeday That is of course true, for that, one could use lodash or another kind of library (or use the polyfill which is linked on the mdn page)

Comment: Not for the arrow function!

Comment: @lonesomeday Ofcourse, I updated the answer, and even linked to the polyfill ;)